# Spring Boot Microservices Deployment

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

Has anyone deployed multiple instances of the same microservice? If so, how are you managing such deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cloud foundry, it's quite straightforward to scale an app to multiple instances once you deploy it.

**For deploy -**

```
cf push -f <deployment manifest file>
```

**For scaling to multiple instances -**

```
cf scale <your_app_name> -i <number_of_instances>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Cloud and Eureka Server for it.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka

Comment: Thanks, used it before.

Answer (score 1):

We are wrapping up everything in docker containers using Kubernetes to manage multiple instances of those.

Comment: Nope! Not really! At least if you don't use Storage Claims.